# Python txt file operation

Tags: python, python-3.x, file

I have a folder with files and want to separate the files in two variables.

For example these are the files:

```
EXfileone.txt
fileone.txt
EXtest.txt
simple.txt
```

Now the thing I can't do is this (in pseudocode):

```
If "EX" in filename:
    add file to variable: EXFILES

IF "EX" not in filename:
    add file to variable : NORMALFILES
```

So now:

```
EXFILES = [EXFfileone.txt, EXtest.txt]
NORMALFILES = [fileone.txt, simple.txt]
```

Then I will use a for loop to make operation with the files:

```
for file in EXFILES:
    ...
```

I'm using Python 3.

Comment: >>> import os
>>> os.listdir()
 Will give you a list of all files in the current folder. Just iterate over it and check if "EX" is available in the filename

Answer (score 3):

You can simply use the standard library `glob` module to match pathnames:

```
import glob


EXFILES = []
NORMALFILES = []

filename_list = glob.glob("*.txt")

for filename in filename_list:
    if "EX" in filename:
        EXFILES.append(filename)
    else:
        NORMALFILES.append(filename)
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```py
from pathlib import Path

folder = Path('/path/to/your/folder')

exfiles = list(folder.glob('EX*.txt'))
normalfiles = [f for f in folder.glob('*.txt') if not f.name.startswith('EX')]
```

That will give you the list of files as you wanted.

But it is better do something like this instead:

```py
from pathlib import Path

folder = Path('/path/to/your/folder')

for f in folder.glob('*.txt'):
    if f.name.startswith('EX'):
       # do something with your EX*.txt file
    else:
       # do something with your normal file
```

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can make each variable a list and store the names of the files in them:

```py
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join

folder_path = '/home/youruser/example' # path to folder

# classify files
exfiles = []
normalfiles= []

for f in listdir(folder_path):
    if isfile(join(folder_path, f)):
        if f.startswith('EX'):
            exfiles.append(join(folder_path, f))
        else:
            normalfiles.append(join(folder_path, f))

for fname in exfiles:
    with open(fname) as f:
        # do operations
```

Answer (score 0):

use the `in` operator. It checks if a string contains a sub-string:

```
from os import listdir

EX_files = []
NORMAL_files = []

for file_name in listdir(): 
    if "EX" in file_name:
        EX_files.append(file_name)
    else:
        NORMAL_files.append(file_name)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use Pythons built-in `filter` and `lambda` functions:

```
import os

my_list = list(filter(lambda x: 'EX' in x, os.listdir(some_dir)))
my_other_list = list(filter(lambda x: 'EX' not in x, os.listdir(some_dir)))
```

Will output two lists filtered with your search criterion.